# What to use for tagging in Django 1.1

Tags: django, django-admin, django-tagging, django-1.1

Unless I'm missing something, it seems django-tagging (0.3) doesnt work on Django 1.1.x. I was having issues then search around and it seems to be the general concensious.

What are other people using? Just in case here is all I'm doing.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = TagField()

tagging.register(Article)

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, { 'fields': ('title', 'tags',)  }),

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

I have a script that added a bunch of tags and they are in the DB without issue. But if I visit the admin, I get

Tags: `[<Tag: []>]`

I don't need advanced features. I just want to have an admin field where I can type in tags, to some related searches based on tags not a whole lot else. Thats about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I coded up this pattern recently using [django-batch-select](http://github.com/lilspikey/django-batch-select), take a look. Obviously you'll still need to code up the admin side of things but it shouldn't be too difficult.